# "docker exec mycontainer --user root" fails with "--user": executable file not found

Tags: docker

I run `docker exec -it 375babe4d6fc --user root /bin/bash` and I get error message as follows:

```
OCI runtime exec failed: exec failed: container_linux.go:346: starting container process caused "exec: \"--user\": executable file not found in $PATH": unknown
```

But I am sure I have succeeded to run this command before.But Now I can only run `docker exec -it 375babe4d6fc /bin/bash` to enter the docker container.

Anybody help? Thank you
My docker's version is 2.1.0.5 on windows

Comment: To be clear, the explicit meaning of the error message is that Docker is trying to run a program named `--user`, but that program is not installed in your container. This is a very strong hint that `--user` is in the wrong position in the command line, which is indeed exactly what you found. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem. It will be OK to use `docker exec -it --user root 375babe4d6fc root /bin/bash`

Comment: This is as described in [POSIX utility syntax guidelines](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap12.html) -- options should always come before positional arguments. GNU tools only enforce that loosely, but that's unfortunate -- the strict way has less to go wrong. (Indeed, almost certainly the reason Docker has strict enforcement is that if it did it the GNU way, it could treat arguments meant for the program you're trying to run as meant for Docker itself).